# Prove $\frac{1+xy+xz}{(1+y+z)^2} + \frac{1+zy+zx}{(1+y+x)^2} + \frac{1+yx+yz}{(1+x+z)^2} \ge 1$ for $x,y,z > 0 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Let $x, y, z > 0$. Prove that
> $$\frac{1+xy+xz}{(1+y+z)^2} + \frac{1+zy+zx}{(1+y+x)^2} + \frac{1+yx+yz}{(1+x+z)^2} \ge 1.$$

I encountered this problem today and thought that it was straightforward, and to be honest it still might be I just can't figure it out for some reason.
I approached this problem using the famous Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. I applied the inequality to every denominator. For example for the first fraction:
$$(1+xy+xz)(1 + \frac{1}{x}+ \frac{1}{x}) \ge (1+y+z)^2$$
After doing this for every fraction I switched the denominator for every one of them with the left side of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Reducing each fraction we are left with
$$\frac{1}{1+2/x} + \frac{1}{1+2/y} + \frac{1}{1+2/z} \ge 1 $$
I am not sure how to continue from here. I tried to use Titu's lemma but it didn't work. I will be very happy if someone can help me out here.

Edit: My Cauchy was wrong.Thanks to all who contributed :)

Comment: Solution on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h331122p1771811

Comment: Check your application of CS inequality on the first fraction - it isn't correct.  Correct it and you'll find the rest a breeze.

Answer (score 2):

Hint :

Can you show ? For $a,b,c>0$

$$\frac{1+ba+bc}{(1+a+c)^{2}}-\frac{b^{2}+ba+bc}{(b+a+c)^{2}}=\frac{\left(b-1\right)^{2}\left(a+c\right)}{\left(a+c+1\right)^{2}\left(a+b+c\right)}\geq 0$$

Comment: The rest is smooth.

Comment: @SuzuHirose The rest is even obvious ^^.

Answer (score 1):

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$
(1+xy+xz)(1+y/x+z/x)
\\
=\left(1,\sqrt{xy},\sqrt{xz}\right)^2
\left(1,\sqrt{ y/x},\sqrt{z/x}\right)^2\geq(1+y+z)^2
$$
which we can rearrange to
$$
{1+xy+xz\over(1+y+z)^2}\geq{x\over x+y+z}.
$$
The rest is smooth.

[Credit](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h331122p1771814)